# ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied while calling createConnection from C++

Tags: oracle, visual-c++

I am trying to create the connection using OCI, but on executing the code I am getting the error

ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied while calling from C++. This seems to be an old error and lots of posts on Google. But, I didn't find any post related to C++. I have Oracle 19 c and Visual Code 2017 installed on Windows 10.

I am able to login into Oracle Sql Developer and didn't face any issue during login.  I would appreciate it if someone throws any hint on this.

Thanks.

```
Environment *env;
Connection *conn;
const string userName = "system";
const string password = "password";
const string connectString = "";
int main()
{
Environment::createEnvironment(oracle::occi::Environment::THREADED_MUTEXED); 
env = Environment::createEnvironment(Environment::THREADED_MUTEXED);
    try {
        conn = env->createConnection(userName, password, connectString);
    }
    catch (const SQLException& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the connection string the same in SQL*Developer as in C++?

Comment: I had tried using the connection string too. 
This is my connection string

const string connectString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=xyz));User Id = system; Password = password";

Comment: It might be an issue with the way the details are passed via the C++ client in terms of their case.  I'd try with SYSTEM not system, and make sure your password is indeed lowercase (or correct case)